# Warning: file_get_contents(image.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in php

Tags: php, wordpress, email-attachments

1.Here i am trying to send my jpg image file as attachment to mail using php mail() 
  function.

2.My mail attachment is sending fine with word document(.doc as attachment).But,throws 
  errorwhen i try to send .jpg as attachment.The code i used:

```
<?php
/*If there is no error, send the email*/
if(isset($_POST['submit-button-name'])) {       
  $uname=$_POST['uname'];                           
  $to = $_POST['mailid'];
  $mobileno=$_POST['mobile'];
  $location=$_POST['location'];
  $from = "Urname <urname@domainname.com>";
  $subject = $_POST['uname']." testing";
  $separator = md5(time());
  /* carriage return type (we use a PHP end of line constant)*/
    $eol = PHP_EOL;
  /*attachment name*/
    $filename = "image.jpg";
    $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('image.jpg')));
  /*main header*/
    $headers  = "From: ".$from.$eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0".$eol; 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$separator."\"";
  /*no more headers after this, we start the body!*/
    $body = "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= "Check out the attachment.".$eol;
 /*message*/
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"".$eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit".$eol.$eol;
    $body .= $message.$eol;
 /*attachment*/
    $body .= "--".$separator.$eol;
$body .= "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"".$filename."\"".$eol; 
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64".$eol;
$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; file=\"".$filename."\"".$eol.$eol;
$body .= $attachment.$eol;
$body .= "--".$separator."--";
 /*send message*/
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    $mail_sent=true;
    echo "<font color='white'>Mail sent</font>";
    $frm="urname@domainname.com";
    $subj="Acknowledgement mail for Brochure form";
    $msg = $_POST['username'] . ",\n\nThank you for your recent enquiry.";
    $body = "Name: ".$_POST['uname'] ."\n\nEmail: ".$_POST['mailid'] ."\n\nMobile: 
        ".$_POST['mobile'] ."\n\nLocation: ".$_POST['location'];
    $headers = 'From: '.'careers@domainname.com';
    mail($frm,$subj,$body,$headers);
} else {
    $mail_sent=false;
}
if($mail_sent == true)
{
/*to clear the post values*/
  $uname="";
  $to="";
  $mobileno="";
  $location="";
}
else{
  echo "Error,Mail not sent";
}
    }
    ?>
```

3.Error being raised as:

Warning: file_get_contents(image.jpg) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to
open stream: No such file or directory in footer.php on line 48

4.I used to receive mail with the body content("Check out the attachment") and having 
  attachment as image.jpg with 0k(no image is opened).

5.please help.thanks in advance.Its urgent.

Comment: why would you use base64_encode? and what does @chunk_split does? are you sure that image.jpg exists on the same folder as the php file where you have this code?

Comment: yaah,both my code and image file is on the same folder.

Comment: if you have any sample file for sending jpg image as attachment.please send.thanks in advance.

Comment: How about try to do something simple like: <?php
$file = file_get_contents('file.jpg');
echo $file;
?> Tell me what you get. Don't forget to substitute file.jpg to the actual file that you have on the same folder where you are running the test script.

Comment: Nothing is eched and same error is being shown.

Comment: that's really weird. How about linking to the file using html: <img src="yourfile"/> do you see anything? Be sure not to include anything else on the script that you're running.

Comment: image icon is displayed,while echoing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13546/discussion-between-kyokasuigetsu-and-vijaya-narayanasamy)

Comment: how about you use absolute path to the image and see if it works. maybe the current working directory is changed somewhere.

Comment: You might also want to check out this older question, it says to split the content headers up and was accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797134/base64-email-attachments-are-not-uploading

Comment: [Use `wp_mail()`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45289/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-wp-mail/45291#45291), not `mail()`.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by giving the full absolute path for my image in this line of my code :

```
$attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('http://wordpress1/wp-content/themes/MyTheme/VyTCDC-brochure.jpg')));
```

So,you can go with your full path.Now,its working like a charm.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

I thought the content type was jpeg not jpg.

`Content-Type: image/jpeg;`

In the section where you add the attachments.

Also the lines:

`$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; file=\"".$filename."\"".$eol.$eol;`

`$body .= "--".$separator."--";`

Probably should be:

`$body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment;".$eol.$eol;`

`$body .= "--".$separator."--".$eol;`

Comment: But,my image is having .jpg extension.is it ok to use image/jpeg in the code?

Comment: attachment below the /*attahment */ comment line

Comment: i changed my code to image/jpeg.still its not working.please help.

Comment: The mimetype is still image/jpeg. This is unlikely to be the cause of the failed to open stream, but it is still wrong. See the [specification on mimetypes](http://www.utoronto.ca/web/htmldocs/book/book-3ed/appb/mimetype.html).

Comment: Yaah,i checked out your link.it was nice and informative.But,in my original code i updated the mime type and my image is of jpeg type with .jpg extension.All are correct.Then,what could be the problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Problem being solved by giving my absolute path to-
    file_get_contents('absolute path');
I used $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'filename';
and it worked out successfully.
Also,i changed image/jpg to image/jpeg.
Thanks to all.